# Android Studio resolves a symbol but cannot locate the package during compilation

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, oltu

I have two modules, `module1` (android library) and `module2` (Java library).

`module1` has `module2` as `implementation` dependency.

`module2` has dependency `d3` which is `org.apache.oltu.oauth2:org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client:1.0.2` as `implementation` dependency.

However, I can import symbols from `d3` in a class in `module1`, without Android Studio complaining. (This would imply that `d3` is in the classpath of `module1` through some other library)

However, on compilation, build for `module1` fails with `error: package org.apache.oltu.oauth2.common does not exist` !?

How is it able to import all symbols from that package when it is not able to resolve it in compile time?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that if the dependency graph is as such:

`app (implementation dependent) moduleA`
`app (implementation dependent) moduleC`
`moduleA (implementation dependent) moduleB`
`moduleC (api dependent) moduleD`

then symbols in `moduleA`, `moduleC` and `moduleD` are visible in `app` (as expected), but surprisingly symbols in `moduleB` are visible too !

However, those symbols in `moduleB` cannot be resolved during compilation of `app` (as expected) .

I am not sure whether this is a feature of Android 3.1.2 which I am using or a bug.